# Game of Life, building the public API - C programming

Tags: c

I'm building the public API for Game of Life and I don't know how to code this part.

This is a picture of "flow chart" we're suppose to follow:

[image]

Steps :
[image]

These are the public APIs we're supposed to fill out;

```
void gofl_get_world(int n_rows, int n_cols, cell_t world[][n_cols], double percent_alive){}
```

this first function should: Get the initial randomly ordered distribution of cells in the world. This is the usage: gofl_get_world(MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLS, world, 0.1)

```
void gofl_next_state(int n_rows, int n_cols, cell_t world[][n_cols]){}
```

This function does this: Calculate the next state of the world according to the rules and the actual state. I.e. this will mark all cells in the world as alive or dead.

Here are the functions we're supposed to build the public API from, I've made these myself as well so they are not pre-defined (they are tested and all returned true):

```
static void get_cells(cell_t arr[], int size, double percent_alive) {
int n = (int) round(percent_alive*size);                          //checking if cell dead or alive with size
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if (i < n ){                                                   //cell needs to be over certain thresh hold to be alive
        arr[i] = 1;                                                //alive
    }
    else{
        arr[i] = 0;                                               //dead
    }
}


static int get_living_neighbours(int n_rows, int n_cols, const cell_t world[][n_cols], int row, int col) {
int sum = 0;                                                                    
for (int r = row - 1; r <=row + 1; r++){
    for(int c = col-1; c<=col +1; c++){
        if(!(row == r && col == c) && is_valid_location(n_rows, n_cols, r, c)){       
            sum = sum + world[r][c];                                                
        }
    }
}
return sum;


static void array_to_matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols, cell_t matrix[][n_cols], const cell_t arr[], int size) {
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){                        
    matrix[i/n_rows][i%n_cols] = arr[i];                
}                                                      


static void shuffle_cells(cell_t arr[], int size) {
for(int i = size; i > 1; i--){
    int j = rand()%i;
    int tmp = arr[j];
    arr[j] = arr[i-1];
    arr[i-1] = tmp;

}
```

Anyone know how I can solve this? I don't know how to perform this action, thanks!

Comment: a) assume we can only read english b) dont post screen shots c) what do you mean by 'public API'

Comment: Hey, I edited the post so you can see the code. The text that's in Swedish is not relevant to the problem, the flow chart is all info we need. They're public API's because they are declared in another file, I will write what they'll do as well. * I'm new to this forum

Comment: do you mean that you do not know how to write callable functions in another file (and then call them) or do you mean that you do not know how to write these specifci functions for the gofl

Comment: I don't know how to write callable functions for these functions in gofl, the private functions (the ones that are filled) are already correct. I just need to fill out the gofl part by calling to these ones, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: the diagrams say that 'gofl_get_world' should be in main.c - not a separate file. Still not really clear what you are asking , maybe those other functions are  in a separate file.

Comment: Both functions are already in main, but if you look at the second picture you see that gofl_get_world walks through get_cells, shuffle etc and gofl_next state is doing something else. That part is what I'm trying to build

Comment: Say so, you're stuck figuring out `gofl_next_state()`? You need to define rules for it & apply them to the matrix(`world`). [Conway's_Game_of_Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)

Comment: So in the gofl_next_state I should make rules with if functions that will call the functions I've already made if they meet the a certain thresh hold? Could you give an example because I don't know how to write it?

Comment: Here is one such example : [Program for Conway’s Game Of Life](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-conways-game-of-life/).